# console.log won't show in firebug on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, firebug, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

In a Facebook page tab, console.log('test'); output won't show in firebug on firefox.
Tried on chrome and they don't show up in firebug either, but they do show up on the javascript console on chrome. But i prefer to work with firefox and firebug.

any idea why?

Comment: Is the Console Panel enabled?

Comment: yes and tried showing every type of error and it's still not there.

Comment: oh now it work even when I uncheck every type of error in firebug even javascript error.. Weird..

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me few days ago and I had to call console.log using the window object

```
window.console.log('whatever');
```

Hope it helps you